# Output the result of a process

Tags: c#, online-compilation

I wanted to make an online c# compiler and also run the compiled program and output it to my website.

How can I do this? I have understood the implementation of the c# compiler but have not been able to display the output of the compiled program on to my website. The `process.Start` function will just initiate the .exe but how do I display the results from that .exe file?

Comment: If you use the `CSharpCodeProvider`, all the messy "wrap up the csc exe" is done for you - you just process the results as properties. However, to echo: running arbitrary code on your server is a very bad thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the process using a `ProcessStartInfo` object specifying `RedirectStandardOutput` to true.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Comment: is there any way to input to the Console ,and how will user know that he has to input something,is there any event for that??

Comment: Then you can also redirect standard input, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx . To tell user to input something, the easy way is associate this info as program description with the program filename in the database and display it before the user runs the program. Or you can write Console.WriteLine("Please input something") in the program since you have redirected the output, but this way you'll have to keep the process/input/output in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [redirect standard ouput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) of your process.

Please note that you need to make sure users aren't running arbitrary code on your server. How do you protect against C# code that tries to format your disc?

Comment: thats a smart question..BTW is there any way to input to the Console(Console.ReadLine) ,and how will user know that he  has to input something,is there any event for that??